# You can now close-vote your own questions?

Tags: support

I noticed a few days ago that you can CV one of your questions. Is this for all stack exchange websites or just for us? I would love that if you CV'ed your own questions, (like a moderator) you can close it instantly.

-I post dumb questions, sorry for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can closevote your own questions if they're not up to the site's quality expectations. You automatically unlock this privilege at 250 reputation, and it has been around for a while now. As said in the [Privileges page](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes):

> #### When should I close my own question?
>
> Questions that are sufficiently off-topic, as outlined in the FAQ, should be closed by casting close votes. Common reasons for question closure are:
>
> - You asked a question that was asked before
> - You asked a question that is off-topic

Typically, though, most self-closed questions are either duplicates of another post (that you didn't just see), or they can't be reproduced because they were fixed.

Remember, closing as a duplicate isn't a punishment -- it acts as a signpost to guide new users to other questions that are far more likely to help them solve their problem. Similarly, closing your own question as off-topic when needed allows us to focus our efforts on solving other problems on-site, wherever they exist.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a new feature but a new privilege for you since you have earned 250 reputation.

[See the Help Centre Page](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes)

You can close vote your own questions (on any site), but the vote is no more powerful than usual. This is nice, since it gives the community a chance to help to make a decision about whether the question really deserves to be closed, or might actually be possible to answer in a way that helps others. Questions and their answers are not just here to help the OP after all :)

That said, when I decided to vote to close one of my own questions, I did so, and I was in chat at the time and dropped in a link to it, saying "VTC my question as no repro since the problem got fixed in an update to the application" and a mod kindly saved everyone the trouble...